# Guessing a pincode with 4 digit.

Tags: combinatorics

A pincode has 4 digit. We know that  one digit is 3 and that no digits are equal. How many times must we guess to find the correct pincode

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Do you want the expected number of times, minimum number of times, or maximum number of times?

Comment: maximum number of times and the answer should be 4016. i understand tha basic of combinatorics and suspect I must use factorial here, but don't know where to satrt

Answer (score 3):

We can use the principle of counting, in order to find out how many combinations are possible within these conditions. Because the pin takes 4 digits we are presented with 4 spaces. First we fix the $3$ on the first position. Next, the condition of no repetition makes us have for the second space the possibility of $9$ different numbers, the ten from $0$ to $10$ except the $3$. For the third position then we have $8$ and for the fourth, $7$. Now a valid choice would be to place the $3$ on the second, third or fourth position so we must multiply the final result by four.
Then $N = 4×9×8×7$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Clear explanation

Comment: Mind accepting my answer? That would be nice

Answer (score 0):

The three unknown distinct digits can form $9\times8\times7$ numbers. And you can insert the $3$ in four positions. Hence $2016$ possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I understand it now